# double negation of arrow in latex

Tags: latex

I use

```
$s \longarrownot\xrightarrow{exm} s'$
```

to have a negation arrow (one slash line) with words upon. I hope to have a double negation arrow with words, i.e., there exist two slash lines on the arrow. What command can I use?

[image]

Comment: Please add a [mre]

Comment: it's not a bug but a question. I mentioned $s \longarrownot\xrightarrow{exm} s'$ could have one slash line, while not sure how to draw two slash lines

Comment: It might not be a bug, but having a compilable test document, ready to copy&paste, is always a nice starting point.

Answer (score 0):

My [`TikZ`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) approach:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}

\begin{document}

\[
s\ {\tikz{%
    \draw[->](0,0)--(1,0);
    \draw(.3,-.1)--(.5,.1);
    \draw(.5,-.1)--(.7,.1);
    \node at (.5,.25) {exm};
}}\ s'
\]

\end{document}
```

and its output (zoomed a lot):

[image: screenshot of output]

[This was the source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/269950/49683) and the inspiration for this answer.